# How to disable cell language pickers in notebooks in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

How to disable cell language pickers in notebooks in Visual Studio Code? I only use Python with markdown so they are useless for me.

[image: Cell language pickers]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is not a way to disable these. If you would like, you could file a suggestions for that here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues.